# Stopping Timer after it have runned one time

Tags: java, timer, delay, actionlistener

In the game that I am making I have a `Timer` that I have set to `10_000` (that's every 10 seconds, right?).

I use this `Timer` to make an power up in the game only last for 10 seconds, the problem is that the Timer doesn't stop after the first time it have runned so the first time the player get that power up it will work fine but if the player get the same power up twice it won't have it for 10 second but depending on the `Timer` the player will get it a random time as long as it isn't over 10 seconds.

What I need to do is making the `Timer` stop right after it runs the first time so that it will start over again the next time the player get that power up.

How would I do this?

Comment: i guess you can call cancel() as last statement in the task()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `Swing Timers` automatically cycle. To run the timer once only, you can use:

```
timer.setRepeats(false);
```

before calling `timer.start()`.